# Update an element from one of multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an object of 4 arrays like following

```js
const data = {
  arr1 : [{id: 1, name: "Mike"}, {id: 2, name: "Peter"}],
  arr2 : [{id: 6, name: "John"}, {id: 9, name: "Mary"}],
  arr3 : [{id: 5, name: "Nick"}, {id: 4, name: "Ken"}],
  arr4 : [{id: 3, name: "Kelvin"}, {id: 7, name: "Steve"}, {id: 8, name: "Hank"}]
}
```

Then I need to find an element and update it. Here is what I tried:

```js
const updateElement = (id: number, newName: string) => {
  let idx: number;

  idx = data.arr1.findIndex((e) => e.id === id);
  if (idx !== -1) data.arr1[idx].name = newName;

  idx = data.arr2.findIndex((e) => e.id === id);
  if (idx !== -1) data.arr2[idx].name = newName;

  idx = data.arr3.findIndex((e) => e.id === id);
  if (idx !== -1) data.arr3[idx].name = newName;

  idx = data.arr4.findIndex((e) => e.id === id);
  if (idx !== -1) data.arr4[idx].name = newName;
}
```

Is there any better way to update an element form multiple arrays than my approach? Suppose that every array has the same element interface.

Comment: Are the ids guaranteed to be unique or would you want to update any and all duplicates?

Comment: @Phil the id is unique and the element exists in one of 4 arrays, no duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `Object.values()` and `flat()` array for update it :

```js
const data = {
  arr1 : [{id: 1, name: "Mike"}, {id: 2, name: "Peter"}],
  arr2 : [{id: 6, name: "John"}, {id: 9, name: "Mary"}],
  arr3 : [{id: 5, name: "Nick"}, {id: 4, name: "Ken"}],
  arr4 : [{id: 3, name: "Kelvin"}, {id: 7, name: "Steve"}, {id: 8, name: "Hank"}]
}
const updateElement = (id, newName) => {
  const values = Object.values(data).flat().find(ele => ele.id === id)
  if(values) values.name = newName
}
updateElement(1, 'newName')
console.log(data)
```